# Reverse for 'likes' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['datasecurity/likes/<int:pk>'] Like buttton error in django

Tags: html, django, fbsdklikebutton

registration and login page is working properly but mine like button is not working .. I don't know why...
Can somebody help me to solve this issue …
it will be great help
please help
Thank you!

1. views.py`

   ```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from datasecurity.models import Post
    from django.urls import reverse
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login required


    # Create your views here.
    def datasecurity(request):
         allPosts= Post.objects.all()
         context={'allPosts': allPosts}
          return render(request, 'datasecurity/data.html',context=context)

    def blogHome(request, slug):
         post=Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
         context={"post":post}
         return render(request, "datasecurity/blogHome.html", context)

    @login_required
    def likes(request, pk):
         post=get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
         post.likes.add(request.user)
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('datasecurity:blogHome', args=str(pk)))
   ```
2. urls.py

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import url

   from . import views

   app_name = 'datasecurity'

   urlpatterns = [
           url(r'^$', views.datasecurity, name="datasecurity"),
           url(r'^datasecurity/(?P<slug>[^/]+)', views.blogHome, name='blogHome'),
           url(r'^likes/<int:pk>', views.likes, name = "likes"),

   ]
   ```
3. data.html

   ```
    {% extends 'careforallapp/navbar.html' %}
    {% block body_block %}
     {% load static %}
   ```

   ### Welcome to Data Security

   ```
       {% for post in allPosts  %}

        <div class="line-dec"></div>
        <span
          >This is a Bootstrap v4.2.1 CSS Template for you. Edit and use
          this layout for your site. Updated on 21 May 2019 for repeated main menu HTML code.</span
        >
      </div>
      <div class="left-image-post">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="left-image">
              {% if post.img %}
                <img src="{{ post.img.url }}" alt="" />
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="right-text">
              <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
              <h6>Article  by {{post.author}}</h6>
              <h2>{{post.datetime}}</h2>

              <p>
                {{post.content|safe | truncatechars:280}}
              </p>

              <from action = "{% url 'datasecurity:likes' pk=post.pk %}" method = "POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" name="post_id" value = "{{ post_id }}" class="btn"> Like 
              </button>
              </form>

              <div class="white-button">
                <a href="{% url 'datasecurity:blogHome' slug=post.slug %}">Read More</a>
              </div><br>
            </div>
               {% endfor %}
   ```
4. error msg `<from action = "{% url 'datasecurity:likes' pk=post.pk %}" method = "POST">`

- Reverse for 'likes' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['datasecurity/likes/int:pk']

this msg was highlighted when I debug the the code. So can someone tell me please what i missed in my code...
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not taking the `pk` argument from view. Change your **view** to:

```
@login_required
 def likes(request, pk):
      post=get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
```

and the **url** to:

```
url(r'^likes/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.likes, name = "likes"),
```

notice the used regular expression in the url.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but it showing me the same error  with highlighting the error msg <from action = "{% url 'datasecurity:likes' pk=post.pk %}" method = "POST">

Comment: Edited the answer. Added the changed url.

Comment: Thank you very much!!... Now it is working.... It is a great help .....

Comment: But Sir, it is not highlighting the users who presses the like button. Can You suggest me any solution of this.... Thank you

Comment: remove value attribute

Comment: No sir, Still not highlighting the user